# macOS Sierra language switch HUD

Tags: macos

On a previous Mac I could switch languages and see a gray box in the middle of the screen that shows which language is selected. This is in addition to the small icon in the top bar.

With the new MacBook Pro and macOS Sierra this language feedback does not show. How to enable it?

Comment: I think it should still be there if you hold down the keys for the shortcut (normally control plus space, but some have command plus space).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work when using the `"Select next source ..."` shortcut, when changing it to use the `"Select the previous ..."` shortcut it does appear!

[image: input sources shortcuts]

Comment: Is this a bug then? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: @MichaelSwarts no idea if this is a bug or by design, and have not had the chance to check in newer macOS versions. But it is what it is, and that's how it is.